# How to send email after upgrade to O365?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

In Office 2013 this VBA code was used in Excel to send email via Outlook.

```vb
Function sendMail(reciever As String, cc As String, subject As String, body As String) As Boolean
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim fileName As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    'On Error GoTo err
    
    With OutMail
        .To = reciever
        .cc = cc
        .BCC = ""
        .subject = subject
        .BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = body
        .Send
    End With
    sendMail = True
    GoTo finally
err:
    sendMail = False
finally:
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Function
```

In O365, on `.Send` command, I get

> Run-time error '287'. Application-defined or object-defined error.

`.Display` is working.

Comment: What happens if you change `.Send` to `.Display` ?

Comment: ```.Display``` is working (opens up an Outlook window with the correctly filled email "form")

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your Trust Center settings then? Or does corporate control that for you?

Comment: Just tried to play with Trust Center settings but unfortunately still the same error (everything in Ad-ins unchecked, ActiveX "Enable all..." and safe mode off, Macro settings "Enable all.." and "Trust access..", Protected view everything unchecked.

Comment: Insert a line `Doevents` before `.Send` and try again?

Comment: Thanks, but still the same issue :( I do not understand it...

Comment: Ok one last thing. Are you runing this from outlook?

Comment: No, I am running it from Excel

Comment: Try googling for `Run-time error '287'. Application-defined or object-defined error.`  There are lot of stackoverflow answer with this search text

Comment: Try (temporarily) remove `.Send` with `.Save`. Does the mail saves in Outlook "Draft" folder?

Comment: Yes, it does get saved in drafts

Comment: I may be a matter of necessary delay before `.Send`. Please, try inserting of the next two lines before it: `DoEvents`  ` Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")`. If it works, try decreasing 03 in 02, 01 until it works (with minimum delay). Let us see it working and we can imagine a loop trying to send after each second and exiting it when the Send command has been sent. But, as I said, let us see this suggestion working...

Comment: If not working, theoretically we can adapt it to run the mail from „Draft” folder... But, I would also like to know that you are trying to send the same mails type, in terms of volume to be sent. My above suggestion is based on the supposition that the code needs to 'prepare' what is to be sent...

Comment: Even with ```DoEvents``` and ```Wait``` I get the same error.

Comment: So, let us try plan B, finding the saved Draft and send it from there. If I remember well, I made such a function in the past. If I will not find it, in principle should know how to build it. And, if you send a comment addressing to me, please tag me (@FaneDuru). Otherwise, I do not receive any notification. You receive notifications only due to the fact that we are commenting on your question...

Answer (score 0):

Try the next way, please. Your adapted code should look like this:

```
Function sendMail(reciever As String, cc As String, subject As String, body As String) As Boolean 'functional (uneori eroare la .Send)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim fileName As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = reciever
        .cc = cc
        .BCC = ""
        .subject = subject
        .BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML
        .htmlBody = body
        On Error Resume Next
         .send
         'the new part_________________________________________________
         If err.Number <> 0 Then
            err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
            .Save
            If Not sendDrafts(reciever, subject) Then
                MsgBox "Not possible to send it from ""Draft"", neither...": Exit Function
            End If
         End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        '_____________________________________________________________
    End With
    sendMail = True
    GoTo finally
err:
    sendMail = False
finally:
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Copy the next function, too (preferable, in the same standard module):

```
Function sendDrafts(reciever As String, subject As String) As Boolean
    Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application, nSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim mpFold As Outlook.Folders, draftFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, i As Long

    Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
    Set nSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set mpFold = nSpace.Folders

    'Set Draft Folder (use your Outlook account):
    Set draftFolder = mpFold("xxxxx@xxxx.com").Folders("Draft")
    
    For i = draftFolder.Items.count To 1 Step -1 'Loop through Draft folder Items
        If Len(Trim(draftFolder.Items.item(i).To)) > 0 Then
            If draftFolder.Items.item(i).To = reciever And _
                     draftFolder.Items.item(i).subject = subject Then
                'Send Item
                draftFolder.Items.item(i).send
                sendDrafts = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

If it does not work in this way, neither, you have a system (security) problem, which does not allow you to programmatically send mails...

I tested on my installation and both ways works.

Comment: @romanzdk Did you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it work as you need?

Comment: yeah I tried it but I got error in the For loop in the ```sendDrafts``` function. I think there is really a security issue. I tried to send it through Sendkeys (alt+s) and it worked for me, but not for colleagues so I guess we will have to display the message and people will have to push send button manually. EDIT: I am sorry, I am unable to tag you I do not know why

Comment: @romanzdk: I suppose that you changed "xxxxx@xxxx.com" with your real Outlook account. Is my supposition correct? Otherwise, you should not receive any error. Only saying something about " I got error in the For loop" is useless... On which line and what error, please?

Comment: yeah I did change the email. I know but it just seemed to me as an security problem thats why I did not described it in more detail. Nevertheless the error was on line ```If Len(Trim(draftFolder.Items.item(i).To)) > 0 Then``` with error "Method To of object MailItem failed". When I check Drafts folder the email IS there with correctly filled items

Comment: I think the problem is some Outlook add-in. When I want to send an email manually I get an pop-up window, where I have to flag (internal flag) the mail and then it is possible to send it. Thats probably why VBA can not send it.

Comment: @romanzdk: Please, put a break on that code line and move the cursor over `draftFolder` variable. Does it show `Nothing` or nothing...? If `Nothing`, you did not use the appropriate mail account, I am afraid. And the error comes only because of the necessary object missing. Does `draftFolder.Items.count` show something? That can be the reason for not sending, but not the error one. If you show me the pop-up window, we'll maybe find a way to automatically press it... If you place `.Dispay` before sending, do you see that message?

Comment: Yeah, ```count``` shows 3. draftFolder has value of "Drafts" (I changed it in code from "Draft")

Comment: @romanzdk: Can you disable the adding in discussion, only in order to see if it is the 'guilty' one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228466/discussion-between-romanzdk-and-faneduru).

Comment: @romanzdk: OK. Does now the code return the same error? What Outlook version do ou use? I tested the code on Office Professional Plus 2016... there the Drafts folder is named 'Draft'.